# MySQL sleeping connection build up

Tags: java, mysql

I have a java application which accesses a MySQL database. When testing locally all the connections are closed properly and not clogging up the amount of allowed active connections, but when I moved this over to a server the connections stopped closing and then they start to build up until their are too many connections.

Comment: might want to add a shutdown hook to your code so that when it exits you are guaranteed to close the connection.

Comment: When an app closes so do all the handles and connections @rabbitguy

Comment: @drew if it doesn't close correctly (exception, forced closed, attacked by midgets, whatever can happen), the connection can remain open which is what sounds like is happening.

Comment: well sure if attacked by midgets, you got me on that one

Comment: I don't want to just shut down the application though it has to be able to constantly be running ready to request data from the database as it is running on a server.